# Look up value based on values in a series of two other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I want to look up a value in column `VAR_1`, based on the values of 'ID_1' and `ID_2'.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(ID_1 = sample(1:10, 10), 
                 ID_2 = sample(1:10, 10), 
                 VAR_1 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10))

df   
   ID_1 ID_2 VAR_1
1     2    7     D
2     6    5     C
3     5    3     B
4     8   10     A
5     9    2     H
6     4    9     E
7     1    6     I
8     7    1     J
9    10    8     F
10    3    4     G
```

Look at the number in `ID_2`, find the matching number in `ID_1` and record `VAR_1` from that row in a new column `RES`

What the result should look like:

```
   ID_1 ID_2 VAR_1 RES
1     2    7     D   J
2     6    5     C   B
3     5    3     B   G
4     8   10     A   F
5     9    2     H   D
6     4    9     E   H
7     1    6     I   C
8     7    1     J   I
9    10    8     F   A
10    3    4     G   E
```

I have tried using `which`, a `for-loop` and `if_else` statements all to no avail, I'm sure it must have a simple solution. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `?match` -

```
df$RES <- with(df, VAR_1[match(ID_2, ID_1)])

   ID_1 ID_2 VAR_1 RES
1     2    7     D   J
2     6    5     C   B
3     5    3     B   G
4     8   10     A   F
5     9    2     H   D
6     4    9     E   H
7     1    6     I   C
8     7    1     J   I
9    10    8     F   A
10    3    4     G   E
```